# c++20 How to make a constrained tuple like container that contains only the allowed types and an instance of itself

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Imagine I want to make a tuple like template container as part of api interface. And I want to constraint it to the list of allowed types plus an instance of this template container. Now I have something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
constexpr const bool bIsAllowedType =
    std::is_same<T, bool>::value ||
    std::is_same<T, void*>::value ||
    std::is_same<T, double>::value ||
    std::is_same<T, int64_t>::value ||
    std::is_same<T, std::string>::value;

template<typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr const bool bIsAllowedArgList =
    bIsAllowedType<std::remove_reference_t<T>> &&
    bIsAllowedArgList<Args...>;

template<typename T>
constexpr const bool bIsAllowedArgList<T> =
    bIsAllowedType<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;

template<typename... Args>
concept CAllowedArgList =
    bIsAllowedArgList<Args...>;

template<CAllowedArgList... Args>
class Container
{
private:
    using TupleT = std::tuple<std::decay_t<Args>...>;
    TupleT data;
public:
    Container() = default;
    Container(Args&&... args) : data(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};

int main()
{
    auto test_cont = Container(1LL, 2.0, std::string("three")); // Ok
    auto err_cont = Container(std::wstring(L"wide string")); // Not ok, type's not allowed
    return 0;
}
```

So, how do I make it to also accept an instance of itself? Like this:

```
int main()
{
    auto test_cont = Container(1LL, Container(2.0, std::string("three"))); 

    return 0;
}
```

I want it to be as simple as possible, so please restraint using third party libs (like Boost) if possible

Comment: For me, not even the first code compiles with `g++ -std=c++2a ...`, with either of the two lines in `main` only. Unrelated comment: if you go for `remove_reference_t`, why don't you also go for [`is_same_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)?

Comment: `1ULL` may not work. gcc11 see it as a different type of `int64_t{1}`
https://wandbox.org/permlink/GN4Li5TNbRQ5fHxJ

Comment: just compiled it using Visual Studio 2019 with experimental features enabled. And is_same_v works as well

Comment: Martin Morterol, it is exactly what I want

Comment: @ШерифГрей well if I stay with ` Container(1LL, 2.0, std::string("three"))` your `\\OK` line doesn't build

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check this by using partial template specialization.

```
template <typename T>
constexpr const bool bIsContainerType = false;

template <typename... Types>
constexpr const bool bIsContainerType<Container<Types...>> = true;
```

Then we just add it to you list of checks in `bIsAllowedType`

```
template<typename T>
constexpr const bool bIsAllowedType =
    std::is_same<T, bool>::value ||
    std::is_same<T, void*>::value ||
    std::is_same<T, double>::value ||
    std::is_same<T, int64_t>::value ||
    std::is_same<T, std::string>::value ||
    bIsContainerType<T>;
```

Since `bIsAllowedType` now needs to know about `Container` which needs to know about our concept I changed `bIsAllowedType` to a struct so we can forward declare it.

```
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct bIsAllowedType;

template<typename... T>
constexpr const bool bIsAllowedArgList =
    (bIsAllowedType<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value && ...);

template<typename... Args>
concept CAllowedArgList =
    bIsAllowedArgList<Args...>;

template<CAllowedArgList... Args>
class Container
{
private:
    using TupleT = std::tuple<std::decay_t<Args>...>;
    TupleT data;
public:
    Container() = default;
    Container(Args&&... args) : data(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};

template <typename T>
constexpr const bool bIsContainerType = false;

template <typename... Types>
constexpr const bool bIsContainerType<Container<Types...>> = true;

template<typename T>
struct bIsAllowedType {
    static constexpr bool value =
        std::is_same<T, bool>::value ||
        std::is_same<T, void*>::value ||
        std::is_same<T, double>::value ||
        std::is_same<T, int64_t>::value ||
        std::is_same<T, std::string>::value ||
        bIsContainerType<T>;
};


int main()
{
    auto test_cont = Container(static_cast<int64_t>(1), 2.0, std::string("three")); // Ok
    //auto err_cont = Container(std::wstring(L"wide string")); // Not ok, type's not allowed
    auto test_cont2 = Container(static_cast<int64_t>(1), Container(2.0, std::string("three"))); 
    return 0;
}
```

Live [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PazsW9)